# jquery-ui - datepicker Not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a two input fields (From and To) which I have converted into date-field using jquery-ui date-picker module by applying `datepicker()` function.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GXhHm/4/)

But the problem with this is in the following scenario:

1. Select From date as 05-22-2013 and To date as 05-22-2013 i.e 22nd May 2013
2. Now when you again click on From field, you can't select any date after 22

I don't know why this issue is coming, in an actual case you should be able to select next dates from From fields.

Let me know if anyone of you have any idea on this.

Thanks,
Dean

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `onSelect` function :

- when you select a date in the **from** input you change the **minDate** selectable in the **to** input with the selected value (eg. 05-22-2013)
- then when you select a date in the **to** input, you change the **maxDate** selectable in the **from** input with the selected value (eg. 05-22-2013)
- so then when you click back to the **from** input you can't select a date after the date selected in the **to** input (eg. 05-22-2013)

Hope this is clear enough :D. Have a look to **[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXhHm/10/)**, i added an alert when you select a date from both calendar to illustrate the problem

Comment: Yes its clear to me now I got the reason..thanks for the answer